# Shared Library Error in SGE qsub script

Tags: shared-libraries, mpi, qsub, sungridengine

I am trying to run a parallel job on a cluster, but every time I do it gives me the error  "error while loading shared libraries: liblammps.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I know that I need to export the library path aka "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library", and when I do that locally and then run the program everything is fine. It's only when I submit the job to the cluster that I run into any issues. My script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library
for i in 1 2 3
do

    qsub -l h_rt=43200 -l mem=1G -pe single 1 -cwd ./Project-Serial.sh
    qsub -l h_rt=43200 -l mem=1G -pe mpi-spread 2 -cwd ./Project-MPI.sh 2
    qsub -l h_rt=28800 -l mem=1G -pe mpi-spread 4 -cwd ./Project-MPI.sh 4
    qsub -l h_rt=19200 -l mem=1G -pe mpi-spread 8 -cwd ./Project-MPI.sh 8
    qsub -l h_rt=12800 -l mem=1G -pe mpi-spread 16 -cwd ./Project-MPI.sh 16
    qsub -l h_rt=8540 -l mem=1G -pe mpi-spread 32 -cwd ./Project-MPI.sh 32

done
```

I'm not sure whether I simply am setting the path in the wrong place? Or maybe there is some other way to use the library? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qsub -v Variable_List` to pass specific environment variables, or `qsub -V` to pass the full environment. From there, you may need to use `mpiexec -x` if the sub-tasks rely on the library file (or `-env` for `mpich`).